# Enhancement SQL query ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have complex SQL query below:

```sql
SELECT 'SA',
       V.CFTCN,
       V.COMIC,
       V.MARCHE,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(V.TRDAC,'[^,]+',1,column_value) RELAC
FROM   (SELECT V.CFTCN,
               V.COMIC,
               V.MARCHE,
               V.TRDAC
        FROM   DEC2A V 
        WHERE  V.ISREP='O' 
        UNION
        SELECT V.CFTCN,
               V.COMIC,
               V.MARCHE,
               V.TRDAC 
        FROM   DCFT2B V
        WHERE V.ISREP='O'
        AND   V.MARCHE NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MARCHE 
                               FROM LTFMAR)
       ) V,
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(V.TRDAC,'[^,]')) +1
           ) as sys.OdciNumberList
         )
       ) 
UNION
SELECT 'VT',
       TRDAC,
       COMIC,
       MARCHE,
       NULL RELAC 
FROM   DCFT3B V
WHERE V.ISREP='O' 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'DA',
       CFTCN,
       NULL COMIC,
       MARCHE,
       NULL RELAC
FROM   CFTCSW
WHERE  DAHIS=TO_DATE('23122021','DDMMYYYY');
```

how can I rewrite my query to get enhance code?
thanks for all

Comment: What does "to get enhance code" mean?  Are you trying to change what the query does?  Fix a compilation error?  Improve performance?  Something else?

Comment: thanks for your feedback the query it's run correctly but I wan to improve performance like the using of V.MARCHE NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT can i replace the not in by other statement ...

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data that is representative of the problem; an English explanation of the query; the expected output for that sample query; and the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for the query.

Comment: Oky I will provid it thank you

Answer (score 2):

`UNION` is much slower than `UNION ALL`; if you do not need to eliminate duplicates than replace all the `UNION`s with `UNION ALL`.

---

```sql
V.MARCHE NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MARCHE FROM LTFMAR)
```

Does not need the `DISTINCT` clause as you do not need to filter out duplicates.

---

Regular expressions are much slower than simple string functions. Your cross join `CAST` & `MULTISET` expression can be rewritten to something like:

```sql
WITH rsqfc (cftcn, /*...,*/ trdac, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT cftcn,
         /* ..., */
         trdac,
         1,
         INSTR(trdac, ',', 1)
  FROM   dec2a
UNION ALL
  SELECT cftcn,
         /* ..., */
         trdac,
         epos + 1,
         INSTR(trdac, ',', epos + 1)
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SELECT cftcn,
       /* ..., */
       CASE epos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(trdac, spos)
       ELSE SUBSTR(trdac, spos, epos - spos)
       END AS relac
FROM   rsqfc;
```

And, although the code is longer, it should be more performant.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8a0e64515970ff2ced4534527246c07e)*

Comment: Exactly it's very specific advices thanks :) :) just how can I avoid using the V.MARCHE NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MARCHE 
                               FROM LTFMAR) and it's possible to replace it by not exists if it will improve the performance ?